# Callout doesn't show confidence intervals

Tags: plotting

[image: why doesn't call out point show confidence bands?]

why doesn't callout show confidence bands?
All data have the same length but to no avail regarding confidence
band for callout point

```
data = {8.12, 7.81, 7.69, 7.72, 7.95, 7.95, 7.47, 7.29, 8.21, 8.19, 
Callout[9.38, "efter lov", Above], 8.11, 7.39, 6.98}; Length[data]
level = 8 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}; Length[level]
varianslista = {2.80, 3.56, 4.85, 3.98, 3.86, 5.1, 5.65, 4.97, 2.9, 
3.12, 0.65, 3.82, 4.78, 4.56}; Length[varianslista]
nlista = {67, 58, 61, 54, 65, 56, 57, 59, 34, 63, 16, 65, 46, 46};
varians = 1.93^2; n = 62;
ListLinePlot[{level, data, data + 0.83 Sqrt[varians/n], 
data - 2.2 Sqrt[varians/n]}, Filling -> {3 -> {4}}, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick],
Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Gray, Tiny], 
Directive[Gray, Small]}, GridLines -> Automatic,
Frame -> True, 
PlotMarkers -> {None, {Graphics[Disk[]], .02}, None, None}, 
ImageSize -> 800, 
PlotLabel -> Style["GFI-indikator elever läsåret 22/23", Black, 20],
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 12], 
DataRange -> {0, Length[data] - 1}, PlotRange -> {3, 10}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code (not an image) that would replicate the picture shown in the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it does not work and the plots get broken is traceable to the following where a `Callout` can't be added to an integer.

```
data + 0.83 Sqrt[varians/n]
```

> {8.32344, 8.01344, 7.89344, 7.92344, 8.15344, 8.15344, 7.67344, 
> 7.49344, 8.41344, 8.39344,
> 0.203442 +    Callout[9.38, "efter lov", Above], 8.31344, 7.59344, 7.18344}

```
data - 2.2 Sqrt[varians/n]
```

> {7.58076, 7.27076, 7.15076, 7.18076, 7.41076, 7.41076, 6.93076, 
> 6.75076, 7.67076, 7.65076, -0.539243 +    Callout[9.38, "efter lov", Above], 7.57076, 6.85076, 6.44076}

---

The `Callout` can be used separately and so with minor rearrangement:

```
data = {8.12, 7.81, 7.69, 7.72, 7.95, 7.95, 7.47, 7.29, 8.21, 8.19, 
   9.38, 8.11, 7.39, 6.98};
level = 8 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
varianslista = {2.80, 3.56, 4.85, 3.98, 3.86, 5.1, 5.65, 4.97, 2.9, 
  3.12, 0.65, 3.82, 4.78, 4.56}
nlista = {67, 58, 61, 54, 65, 56, 57, 59, 34, 63, 16, 65, 46, 46}
varians = 1.93^2
n = 62;

ListLinePlot[{level, data, data + 0.83 Sqrt[varians/n], 
  data - 2.2 Sqrt[varians/n], 
  Callout[{{10, 9.38}}, "efter lov", Above, {10, 9.38}, 
   LeaderSize -> {20, 90 °, 4}, CalloutStyle -> Red]}
 , Filling -> {3 -> {4}}
 , PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Black, Thick]
   , Directive[Red, Thick]
   , Directive[Gray, Tiny]
   , Directive[Gray, Small]
   }
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotMarkers -> {None, {Graphics[Disk[]], .02}, None, None}
 , ImageSize -> 800
 , PlotLabel -> Style["GFI-indikator elever läsåret 22/23", Black, 20]
 , LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 12]
 , DataRange -> {0, Length[data] - 1}
 , PlotRange -> {3, 10}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this answer :)

Comment: What is the easiest way if I want to start numbering from e.g week 34 instead of from 0?

Comment: @runner You can change `DataRange` and add `34` as well to the `Callout` 's x-position manually.

Comment: Next question :). How do I account for a new year? 34-52 is ok but what happens when I want to add week 1 after week 52?

Comment: You can stretch the `DataRange` idea so far. You will probably have to explore `DateListPlot`. It would be better to start a fresh post once you have tried out the examples from the docs.

Comment: @runner You got a good answer to your question. If you have other questions, ask them as such. The comments are not a place to move the goalposts of your questions for eternity.

Comment: @runner you can accept the solution if it has answered the OP by clicking the checkmark next to it.